# Do I have to import modules in powershell runbook (azure)?

Tags: azure, powershell, module, azure-resource-manager, account

I just want to run a simple Powershell-script in an Azure Runbook. After complete the script in the testing pane powershell doesn't recognize "Connect-AzureRmAccount" as an command. It's weird because in another runbook I can run the same command without problems.

Normally, you have to install and import the required module, but this isn't available in a runbook.

Do you have any suggestions?

Best regards

Comment: Here is the Official Microsoft Link: [Import a module from the Modules gallery in the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-runbook-gallery#import-a-module-from-the-modules-gallery-in-the-azure-portal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to install or import-module into a runbook. See this link: https://sharepointyankee.com/2018/02/26/importing-powershell-modules-into-azure-automation/

Comment: Instead of the Link to Internet link, can you please instead write up the full answer?